# Where is the login policies table of an MS sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to Microsoft SQL 2012 (x64 bit).

I need to view the login policies that is set for each account. I need to do this on a SQL Server Authentication (Non-Windows Authentication)

Both Server Level, (i.e. From **sys.server_prinicipals**) and Database Level (i.e. From **sys.database_principals**).

I am already aware of how to view it in the **GUI**.

[image: Login - New]

Answer (score 0):

These boxes only apply to SQL Server authenticated logins.

So you can find the values in [`sys.sql_logins`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355.aspx)

Comment: Is it the one different for every instance of a server?? I basically need details of all the users, logins of a database, server respectively. And I need them in a table format for easy viewing. Any T-SQL command would also help.